# How to reduce an array down to only it's 'keys' in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm starting out with this array, of which I only need the numbered keys:

```
Array
(
    [4118] => Car
    [4668] => Bus
)
```

and I've whittled it down to this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4118
    [1] => 4668
)
```

but for some reason, drupal and the code I'm working with will only fully accept an array in this format (and also my preferred format):

```
array(4118,4668);
```

or this one:

```
array(0 => 4118,1 => 4668);
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) just for that.

Comment: Yeah, that was the first thing I tried, but it returns this: array
(
    [0] => 4118
    [1] => 4668
)
which my code is actually misinterpreting. When I manually create an array in my preferred format above, it interprets it correctly.

Comment: @user526120 But that's the same thing as `array(4118,4668)`. You are confounding it with the print_r() output I think. Maybe you should show us your other code.

Comment: They are different in that one has brackets around the key, and the other doesn't. When I assign the bracketed one to a field, it misinterprets it, when I assign one without brackets, it interprets correctly. The code is drupal's http://drupal.org/project/node node module. In a hook_nodeapi I'm assigning the array to $node->taxonomy and yeah, I did print_r();

Comment: @user526120: Nope. There are definitely no brackets around the keys. This is what print_r and var_dump add. But the array itself is a list with incremental integers for keys.

Comment: Oh. So if I print_r() on the array and it comes out correct with brackets, it is the same as the array that I manually created without the brackets? What does it mean if you print_r(); on an array and get the number 1?

Comment: @user526120: Yes, it's identical. You can use `var_export()` to verify. This will also better differentiate between integer `1` and a string `'1'` key. If you actually had an array key with brackets, then print_r would show it as `[[1]]`. If print_r outputs nothing but a 1, then you gave it a single numeric variable instead of an array. -- Btw, can't dig up the drupal node->taxonomy code, you should post the relevant part.

Comment: Ok, so after more debugging (this is my third day working on this), a contributed drupal module (contributed by respected studio) is to blame. So I was concentrating on the wrong end, it's the code that is spitting out the array that is the problem! Well, I'm sure your answer will be of use to someone, thanks.

Comment: @user526120: No worries. You've also been the victim of one of PHPs peculiar features (print_r), so interesting to note anyway.

Comment: @user526120: It's near impossible to write bug free code, even for "respected studio's". Please be so kind to give back to the community and submit a bug report in the module's issue queue at the drupal.org website.